# Range of $f(x) = \sin(\cos x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Problem :

Finding the maximum and minimum value of the function :

$f(x) = \sin(\cos x)$

My approach : 
We know that if $f'(x) > 0 $ function attain maximum value by putting $f'(x) = 0$ and taking the second derivative test ie. $f''(x) >0$ then function is minimum and if $f''(x) <0$ function is maximum this can be obtained by putting the value of $x$ (derived from $f'(x) =0$)

Now the given function is :

$f(x) = \sin(\cos x)$

$f'(x) = -\sin x \cos(\cos x) $

How can we do this with the help of calculus?

Comment: Well $f'(x)=0$ when sin(x) is 0 or when cos(cos(x)) is 0. Can you figure out when this is the case?

Answer (score 5):

$\cos x$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$, and $\sin x$ is increasing on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, so since $[-1,1]\subset (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ the minimum and maximum are $\sin(-1)$ and $\sin(1)$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(x) \cos(\cos(x))=0$ implies either $\sin(x)=0$ and/or $\cos(\cos(x)=0$.